# Dereferencing a structure pointer and storing it vs a pointer vs memcpy?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have a structure

```
    typedef struct 
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    } s_sample_t;
```

suppose now if I have a pointer to a structure,

```
s_sample_t s2 ;
memset (&s2,0,sizeof(s2))
void* s1 = &s2
s_sample_t s3 = *(s_sample_t*)s1;
```

Clearly, s1 is a pointer to s2.
What happens in memory when dereferencing is done for s1 and how does it differ from

```
memcpy(&s3,s1,sizeof(s3));
```

When should we use/not use the dereferencing?

i.e should it be

```
s_sample_t s3 = *(s_sample_t*)s1; 
s3.a etc
```

or

```
s_sample_t* s5 = (s_sample_t*)s1;

s5->a etc;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use the easiest way to copy objects and let the compiler sort it out. Micro-benchmarks are extremely hard to get right, and would probably say exactly the same anyway. Also, keep track of what you want to work on: The pointer, the pointee, which level?

Comment: Think you want to compare `memcpy(&s3,s1,sizeof(s3));`.  `sizeof(s1)` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: @user3386109: Makes things a bit clear now!

Comment: @chux : Yes! Sorry my bad! Edited the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I guess that makes a difference. Modification of data vs accessing can help decide.

Comment: As you have experienced, `s_sample_t s3 = *(s_sample_t*)s1;` is better than `memcpy(&s3,s1,some_size);` as code sometimes uses the wrong `some_size`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, actually!

Comment: i would say, when thing comes to complicated, `s_sample_t s3 = s2;` kind may be POSSIBLE to do more work than you expect, since there are some "junk" bytes generated for alignment. i have read that in some case, it's better to copy it by hand, field by field. but your case is simple enough, seems no this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has two parts:

1. In general, dereferencing a struct pointer and doing `memcpy` are the same thing. The first is probably easier to read, but aside from that you should not experience much difference between the two.
2. Dereferencing the entire structure (`s_sample_t s3 = *(s_sample_t*)s1; ...`) makes a copy of your struct. Dereferencing individual fields (`s_sample_t* s5 = (s_sample_t*)s1; s5->a;`) only accesses the fields you need. The first option is generally better if you need to copy the whole structure, since the single operation will almost certainly be more efficient than copying everything field by field. If you do not need a copy of the entire structure, using arrow notation is probably better since you do not have to copy unnecessary memory.

Comment: @chux, Although I disagree with your point, I do agree that it does not belong in an answer to this quesiton. Edited out.

Answer (score 2):

`s3` is a copy of `s2` (using memcpy vs dereferencing s1 makes no difference) so changes made to `s3` have no effect on `s2`. `s5` is a pointer to `s2`, so changes made to `s5->a` will effect `s2.a`.

Here's some code that demonstrates this

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} s_sample_t;

int main( void )
{
    s_sample_t s2 = { 222, 888 };
    void *s1 = &s2;

    // make a copy of s2 by dereferencing s1
    s_sample_t s3 = *(s_sample_t*)s1;
    s3.a = 333;
    printf( "s2.a=%d s2.b=%d\n", s2.a, s2.b );
    printf( "s3.a=%d s3.b=%d\n\n", s3.a, s3.b );

    // make a copy of s2 using memcpy
    s_sample_t s4;
    memcpy( &s4, s1, sizeof(s4) );
    s4.a = 444;
    printf( "s2.a=%d s2.b=%d\n", s2.a, s2.b );
    printf( "s4.a=%d s4.b=%d\n\n", s4.a, s4.b );

    // create a pointer to s2 called s5
    s_sample_t *s5 = s1;
    s5->a = 555;
    printf( "s2.a=%d s2.b=%d\n", s2.a, s2.b );
    printf( "s5->a=%d s5->b=%d\n\n", s5->a, s5->b );
}
```

In the first two cases, the value of `s2.a` is unaffected and will print 222. But after the line
 `s5->a = 555;` the value of `s2.a` will be 555.